# What happens if I edit a framework code in Xcode that was added using pods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I added a framework to my project in Xcode written in Swift. There was some issue in the framework so I tried to modify and a dialog came out giving me the option to lock or unlock, so I choose Unlock and proceed.

Would it harm the owner? Would these changes continue with my project until my app is in the App Store? Please let me know if there is an issue with that and help with a solution.

Simply I need all framework files but I don't need all functions. In addition, I need to add functions to fit to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not recommended to modify a third party pod's code,** as it will be overwritten with the next `pod update`.

There are multiple solutions you can try:

- implement the framework manually and modifying it there (keep in mind that you are losing the capability of quick updating)
- modify it as an extension of the framework if possible, i. e. store your changes in a separate file and paste it everytime an update occurs (not recommended as it is not too convenient)
- fork the project and make changes on that separate fork
- create a pull request to the project that includes the modifications (if you think they are helpful for others as well)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was clear and helpful. I think I will go with the first solution, I will look for an explanation to do the solution in a right way.